# How can I change java.util.Date to ISO String using ThreeTenABP

Tags: java, android, datetime, iso8601, threetenbp

I'm using ThreeTenABP for converting date time for Android. 
My question is how can I change a `java.util.Date` to an ISO String (format is `2018-05-24T02:33:10.062Z`) by ThreeTenABP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [ThreetenABP-solution](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/DateTimeUtils.html#toInstant(java.util.Date)) can look like this:

```
java.util.Date d = ...;
org.threeten.bp.Instant instant = org.threeten.bp.DateTimeUtils.toInstant(d);
String iso = instant.toString();
```

If you wish more control over formatting then you can convert the instant to a `ZonedDateTime` (or better [to an OffsetDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#atOffset-java.time.ZoneOffset-)) and use a dedicated `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: You save my day too. That's more relevant  answer for my question

Comment: @OleV.V. I agree that using a fixed offset and hence the type `OffsetDateTime` is here the natural choice. Have adjusted the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know about android, but if `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` is available you could do:

`new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").format(new Date())`

Comment: Currently ur answer suitable for me. But I also need with `threetenabp`

Comment: Escaping the pattern letter "Z" is a heavy mistake resulting in wrong data. But using the pattern letter "X" is a good alternative.

Comment: There is a way through to getting the string with correct time *and* the `Z` with `SimpleDateFormat` (at least if your Android API level is high enough), but it’s not straightforward. Since `SimpleDateFormat` is both outdated and notoriously troublesome, I’d rather not bother, and would use [the good answer by Meno Hochschild](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50641263/5772882) instead.

Comment: yes, of course it is better to set a timezone on the format. next time i'll be more cautious when posting answers.

Answer (score 0):

Expression:

```
new Date().toInstant().toString()
```

results in

```
2019-12-31T06:32:37.997Z
```